# php's function crypt() strong salt

Tags: php

Is the salt good and strong enough to be used with `ctypt()`? If not, what can I add to make it stronger?

```
$cost = 10;    
$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
$salt = sprintf("$2a$07$", $cost) . $salt;
```

Another Question: Why do I need to store the salt?

I am checking like so:

```
if(crypt($_POST['password'], $pass_db) === $pass_db){echo "";}else{echo "No";}
```

Comment: About the "why store salt" part, how can you use the password without the salt?

Comment: Coming up with your own cryptography is hard. Why not use existing solutions like `bcrypt`? https://gist.github.com/1053158

Comment: in your check you use 2 times $pass_db, one time for crypt and to match so far as I can see that will never match.

Comment: but blowfish adds the salt to the password, then all I have to do is to use the password for the salt.

Comment: @Laurent but every time I run that function, it gives me different string of text. How can compare it?

Comment: This looks alright to me on first sight. But since subtle mistakes can make or break this kind of thing very quickly, I'd compare it to a known vetted implementation or use that vetted implementation outright: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: One mistake is already that you're not actually sprint-effing the `$cost` into the string.

Comment: @MaxPain, this is because the string includes the salt and encrypted string, and the salt is randomly generated. Using the lib is actually very simple: `$hash = bcrypt_hash($pwd);` then to check: `$pwdOk = bcrypt_check($pwd, $hash);`